# libR.so not found in R Rstudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, shared-libraries, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install RStudio (v1.2.5033) on Ubuntu (v18.04) but in the end, it doesn't work and I don't really understand the error...

To install R I followed cran instructions:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that I downloaded Rstudio from its website (https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.2.5033-amd64.deb) and installed but when I tried to lunch I find the following error:

```
R shared library (/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so) not found. If this is a custom build of R, was it built with the --enable-R-shlib option?
```

I look for this lib in and created a soft link to the path where it wasn't find...

```
$ locate libR.so
/usr/lib/libR.so
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so

$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libR.so /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so
```

And now the error is different:

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: solved! the steps were: download code and compile it from cran using the flag recommend (`--enable-R-shlib`)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I installed R studio instead R-4.1.0 go ahead. So, I need to copy libR.so from  /usr/lib/R/lib to /usr/local/lib/R/lib/.